# how to end a thread when it is in sleep?

Tags: blackberry

i am making a project in which i ahve shedule somthing happen after a certain period of time,
i calculate that time an pass that time in sleep method.
if i again changes the time then i want to end previous thread and start a new thread.
so i want to know how to end the thread which is in sleep method without executing it's run method.

Comment: Can you give more info on the language you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume Java when you are programing for Blackberry?

If yes, don't use `Thread.sleep()` to wait, but instead `wait()` on a monitor, which you can then `notifyAll()`, i.e.

```
private Object waitObject = new Object();

public void doWait() {
  synchronized (waitObject) {
    waitObject.wait(10*1000); // wait up to 10 seconds
  }
}

public void wakeUp() {
  synchronized (waitObject) {
    waitObject.notifyAll();
  }
}
```

The `synchronized` blocks are important, as you need to own the monitor you want to wait on or notify on.